# Any cost associated with creating the cloudfront distribution from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When you setup a cloudfront distribution for the first time from an S3 bucket, does Amazon charge you for migrating the data to the edge locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, CloudFront doesn't automatically download all the data from your S3 bucket. It only loads a file from S3 the first time that file is requested.